# Dynamic CRM 2015 Business Process Flow Editing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015, business-process

I am trying to edit the BPF element in a Case form to remove the highlighted  field in the below image:

[image]

I am fairly new to CRM 2015, does anyone know how i can do that ?
I have tried the ribbonworkbench and the form editor and could not find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Business Process Flows are a Process-type component, so you can edit them under `Settings -> Processes` or inside your solution under `Components -> Processes`.

Comment: I don't have any records under `Settings -> Processes` and i can see a lot of records under `Components -> Processes` for the Case Entity. I'll look into this.. looks promising, thanks!

Comment: I cannot see it under 'Components -> Processes' either, what i'm trying to do is remove the 'Assign to Others' field when the BPF is in the research stage, any other suggestions would be appreciated..

Comment: are you a system administator? did you select the view "All Processes"? maybe you have my processes as default

Comment: Yes, it was "My Processes" by default! I found it in 'Settings -> Processes' under the "Activated Processes" view and was able to remove the field. Thanks a lot Guido!